# Multiple maven plugins to run a phase

Tags: java, maven, plugins, soapui, ready-api

I am doing a maven smartbear soapui project. I have dependency for two plugins. `

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pro</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <projectFile>${projectFile}</projectFile>
              <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
              <junitReport>true</junitReport>
              <exportAll>true</exportAll>
              <printReport>true</printReport>
              <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <soapuiProperties>
            <property>
              <name>soapui.logroot</name>
              <value>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/</value>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>soapui.https.protocols</name>
              <value>TLSv1.2,SSLv3</value>
            </property>
          </soapuiProperties>
        </configuration>

        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>redfish</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <testSuiteProperties>
                <properties>
                  <property>PropertyCode=${propertyCode}</property>
                  <property>Environment=${environment}</property>
                  <Gateway>Gateway=${gateway}</Gateway>
                </properties>
              </testSuiteProperties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>`
```

My tests need to have dependency plugin redfish as it supports soapuiTestSuite properties configuration.

Now when I tried to run this `mvn install test`, the build starts to run with first plugin and fails as it doesn't have second plugin downloaded and later runs again downloading second but fails. I need to have both the plugins and whole configuration setup before I run the goal.

I am new to Maven structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add execute at the second plugin.
2. For example, if you want to execute maven-soapui-extension-plugin before soapui-pro-maven-plugin you can add this execution:

   ```
       <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>soapui-tests</id>
                     <phase>verify</phase>
                     <goals>
                      <goal>test</goal>
                     </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
   ```
3. And just do 'mvn install', because you have executions attached to default Maven lifecycle.

Look at the list of default Maven Lifecycle in the execution order: validate, initialize, .. deploy ([docs here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)).

Comment: my project depends on both the plugins. As per your statement, only one plugin would get executed right?

Comment: no, attaches each plugin to a phase to master the order of execution of these plugins